# Can't insert data in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

i can't complete signup, cause the data is not inserted in the database. please help me
Any help will be helpful. thank you so much

```
<?php
//signup.php
include 'connect.php';
include 'header.php';


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')
{ 
/*the form hasn't been posted yet, display it
  note that the action="" will cause the form to post to the same page it is on */
echo '<table><th><center><h2>Sign Up</h2></center></th><tr><td><form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="user_idnum" placeholder = "ID Number"/><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="user_lname" placeholder = "Lastname"/><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="user_fname" placeholder = "Firstname"/><br><br>
    <input type="password" name="user_pass" placeholder = "Password"><br><br>
    <input type="password" name="user_pass_check" placeholder = "Re-enter Password"><br><br>
    <input type="email" name="user_email" placeholder = "Email"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" />
 </form></td></tr></table>';

}
else
{
/* so, the form has been posted, we'll process the data in three steps:
    1.  Check the data
    2.  Let the user refill the wrong fields (if necessary)
    3.  Save the data 
*/
$errors = array(); /* declare the array for later use */

if(isset($_POST['user_idnum']))
{
if(strlen($_POST['user_idnum']) > 10)
    {
        $errors[] = 'The ID number cannot be longer than 10 characters.';
    }


}
else
{
    $errors[] = 'The ID number field must not be empty.';
}

if(isset($_POST['user_pass']))

{
    if($_POST['user_pass'] != $_POST['user_pass_check'])
    {
        $errors[] = 'The two passwords did not match.';
    }
}
else
{
    $errors[] = 'The password field cannot be empty.';
}

if(!empty($errors)) /*check for an empty array, if there are errors, they're in this array (note            the ! operator)*/
{
    echo 'Please input correct information...';
    header ("refresh:3;url=signup.php" );
}
else
{
    //the form has been posted without, so save it
    //notice the use of mysql_real_escape_string, keep everything safe!
    //also notice the sha1 function which hashes the password
    $sql = "INSERT INTO
    users(user_pass, user_email ,user_date, user_level, user_lname, user_fname,   user_idnum)
            VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_idnum']) . "',
                   '" . sha1($_POST['user_pass']) . "',
                   '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_email']) . "',
                    NOW(),
                    0)";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if(!$result)
    {
        //something went wrong, display the error
        echo 'Something went wrong while registering. Please try again later.';
        header ("refresh:3;url=signup.php" );

    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Successfully registered. You can now <a href="signin.php">Sign in</a>';
    }
}
}


?>
```

i don't know what is wrong, all i can see after i clicked the Sign up button is always "Something went wrong while registering. Please try again later."
please help me, i need this to complete my project. thankyou

Comment: You're mixing MySQL APIs for *one* thing. `$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));` - You're probably mixing for your connection too.

Comment: You want to insert into 7 fields, but you present only 5 values.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: you cannot use mysql_real_escape_string in mysqli_query there is a mysqli_* version of real escape i think =)

Comment: @MarcoMura you can a returned string is a returned sting so long as mysql_real_escape_string works it will provide an output that works for all MySQL Queries!, mysqli, mysql and PDO in the end produce MySQL Valid queries its just how php talks to the MySQL Server that differs in the end result

Comment: @MartinBarker In other words, you're saying mixing APIs is allowed and my 4 upvotes (so far) were uncalled for and I would be wrong, correct?

Comment: @Fred-ii- it is allowed it just not recommended! hance the upvotes you did not say your not allowed to mix unlike Marco Mura who did say that!

Comment: @MartinBarker I should have written: *"You're mixing alcohol with driving a motor vehicle"* instead. My bad.

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO users(user_pass, user_email ,user_date, user_level, user_lname, user_fname, user_idnum) VALUES('" . sha1($_POST['user_pass']) . "',
        '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_email']) . "',
      NOW(),0,'".($_POST['user_lname'])."','".($_POST['user_fname'])."', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_idnum']) . "')";

problem solve, thank you so much guys

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

to

```
$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);
```

or change everywhere `mysql` to `mysqli` and then check do you have mysqli extension installed or enabled.

Check http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php

Comment: You should use mysqli_* functions rather than mysql_* as they are deprecated.

Comment: only in php 5.5 before that just not recommended

Comment: By the way, in `mysql_`, the connection comes last `$result = mysql_query($sql, $con)` @frantsium - `mixed mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )` as per the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: Something I fixed in an edit. ^^^

Comment: Just another note with the `mysql_` functions you dont need to specify the connection handler if it's all though one connection it will always use the last opened connection failing that it will create a connection using the settings inside the php.ini all `mysql_` function do this,
It's one of the little things that niggles me about `mysqli` it says its procedural but its not it's functional as you have to use the return of the `mysqli_connect` it requires the parameters so technically it's functional code design not procedural :)

Answer (score 1):

i already fix it and able to insert in database, one problem is, the lname and fname is totally blank in the database even I input a value in it.

```
"INSERT INTO users(user_pass, user_email ,user_date, user_level, user_lname, user_fname, user_idnum)
            VALUES('" . sha1($_POST['user_pass']) . "',
                   '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_email']) . "',
                    NOW(),0,'','','" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_idnum']) . "')";
```

Comment: So you used my Answer using mysql_real_escape_string though a mysqli query?

Comment: i just got an idea on your answer and to the others comment, thankyou

Answer (score 0):

So this is your query

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO
    users(user_pass, user_email ,user_date, user_level, user_lname, user_fname,   user_idnum)
            VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_idnum']) . "',
                   '" . sha1($_POST['user_pass']) . "',
                   '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_email']) . "',
                    NOW(),
                    0)";
```

So a break down of the columns your telling mysql you want to put data into

```
user_pass, 
user_email ,
user_date, 
user_level, 
user_lname, 
user_fname,   
user_idnum
```

the data you want to insert

```
 VALUES(
'" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_idnum']) . "',
'" . sha1($_POST['user_pass']) . "',
'" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_email']) . "',
NOW(),
0)
```

So my SQL will use like

```
user_pass = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_idnum']) . "', 
user_email = '" . sha1($_POST['user_pass']) . "', ,
user_date = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_email']) . "', 
user_level = NOW(), 
user_lname = 0, 
user_fname,   // ERROR NO VALUE DEFINED
user_idnum    // ERROR NO VALUE DEFINED
```

So you have this just all wrong your telling my sql you want to insert data into 2 without the data for them

Your columns and insert values are in the wrong order.

your query should be

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_idnum, user_pass, user_email, user_date, user_level) 
VALUES(
'" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_idnum']) . "', 
'" . sha1($_POST['user_pass']) . "', 
'" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_email']) . "',
NOW(),
0
)";
```

Comment: this is only to match your insert values no i have explain why it is wrong and showed you how it should be correct your query to have the values you want and the make sure the order of the `VALUES` is the same order of the columns your inserting into

Comment: Nice explanation, but still incorrect. Read my first comment under OP's question and the others.

Comment: And look at my Comment you can if you really wanted but not recommended mix `mysql_real_escape_string` with a `mysqli_query` as it just returns a string the only way `mysql_real_escape_string` would fail to return a string would result in a PHP error not a mysql error `http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string` so long as it can connect it will work and the php.ini can have the connection info for it

Comment: No, no, no no... and again, no. I'll get 50 guys here in 5 minutes that will tell you, that you can't mix APIs. Like using this will work? `$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);` - I obviously haven't been doing this stuff long enough.

Comment: Well your 50 Guys are WRONG!!!, so long as a connection can be made to the Server E.G the config is in the php.ini it will work!

Comment: @MartinBarker Care to set up a demo demonstrating that mixing APIs works? AFAIK mysql functions return a mysql resource and not a mysqli resource and they are not compatible.

Comment: i Already was http://pastebin.com/44jgGqTs there you go if you look at the docs `mysql_real_escape_string` & `mysqli_real_escape_string` return strings not resourses

Comment: `$someMySQLIText = mysqli_real_escape_string($someVal);` right, so where's the connection parameter? as per documentation http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: not required go read the docs

Comment: No, YOU read the docs http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php Procedural style
`string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )`

Comment: we dont know if he is using mysql or mysqli coz we cant see `connect.php`

Comment: Sorry my bad on that i meant to do it on the mysqli not on the mysql version corrected here http://pastebin.com/mNAEGiqN

Comment: and please stop editing your comments to include stuff you have put in comments after!

Comment: I'm assuming that OP is using `mysql_` functions to connect with. Therefore and if I'm right, `$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);` should be changed to `$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);` Only then will it work.

Comment: Your example fails becuase you are establishing two connections in your code. That's not what is happening here. You can't establish a mysqli connection and then use mysql functions.

Comment: assuming is not correct we don't know! my point was that his code would work he is using `mysql_real_escape_string` with a mysqli query it will work ok the other way would not

Comment: Read the docs for it `mysql_real_escape_string` will open a connection if one is not already open using the php.ini settings! 
`The MySQL connection. If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed. If no such link is found, it will try to create one as if mysql_connect() was called with no arguments. If no connection is found or established, an E_WARNING level error is generated.`

Comment: I'll tell you what. Setup a DEMO and not a pastebin file, using `mysqli_` functions to connect with, then `mysql_` functions to do the rest (query, escaping) and *vice-versa*. Try it out yourself. You'll see.

Comment: move into http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67232/martins-room all the evidance of it working is in there! now

Comment: @MartinBarker I agree to 100% with Fred -ii- and John Conde! You are just wrong. No more words to say